# jquery animate divs in grid

Tags: jquery, html

I have a grid of divs that looks like a table.

```
#wrapper
 > div.container > h2 (hidden)
 > div.container > h2 (hidden)
 > div.container > h2 (hidden)
</>
```

I want to animate the background color of the hovered div and display the h2 in it.

my code looks like this.

```
$('.container').hover(function() {
    $('.container>h2').stop().fadeOut(200);
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#3e95ff' }, 300);
},function() {
    $('.container>h2').stop().fadeIn(200);
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 300);
});
```

Problem is when I hover a div all of the h2's are shown. How can I select only the h2 of the hovered div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
$('.container>h2').stop().fadeIn(200);
```

with

```
$(this).find('h2').stop().fadeIn(200);
```